# Avoiding "'NoneType' object is not iterable" error when passing 'None' in nested loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass three lists into a function that will then iterate over all values in the lists, and fire them into another function:

```
def main():
    l1 = [0,1]
    l2 = [1,5,10,20]
    l3 = [15]

    my_func(l1,l2,l3)

def my_func(l1, l2, l3):
    nested = ((x,y,x) for x in l1 for y in l2 for z in l3)
    for x,y,z in nested:
        another_func(x,y,z)

def another_func(x,y,z):
    ...
```

However occasionally I'll need to pass in a None value as one of the lists:

```
l3 = None
```

This results in the error: **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable**, because it doesn't like the None value when trying to iterate.

I was wondering if there's any way to exclude lists from the iteration if their value is None?

Comment: Did you mean `nested = ((x,y,z)...`?

Comment: Is `l3` is `None`, what do you expect the `z` values to be?

Comment: I was expecting them to also be None, is that not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Here I go through all the lists, replacing `None` with `(None,)` which is a tuple and therefore iterable

```
from itertools import repeat, product

def my_func(*lists):
    for group in product(*(l if l is not None else (None,) for l in lists)):
        another_func(*group)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I think what I'm looking for is the following:

```
list(itertools.product(*filter(None, (a,b,c))))
```

This will loop over all possible iterations and filter the lists for None.